# Translating word arrays in Ruby on Rails I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, internationalization

I've searched and fiddled, but I'm having no luck. I'm trying to figure out the best way to translate a word array (model file):

```
  def self.valid_batman_characters
    %w{batman joker}
  end
```

I thought something like I18n.t ['activerecord.lookup', 'activerecord.lookup'] would work, but no dice. I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing?

Comment: `['lookup', 'lookup'].map {|lookup| I18.t lookup}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
%w{batman joker}.map{ |key| I18n.t(key, scope: "active_record") }
```

Alternatively, you could use symbols:

```
%i{batman joker}.map{ |key| I18n.t(key, scope: :active_record) }
```

Or strings, without specifying scope to I18n, like so:

```
%w{batman joker}.map{ |key| I18n.t("active_record.#{key}") }
```

Or symbols **and** strings, just because you can:

```
%w{batman joker}.map{ |key| I18n.t(key, scope: :active_record) }
```

That is all assuming that you have the keys in your language config set up the following way:

```
active_record:
  batman: Translation1
  joker: Translation2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked at the documentation but just dind't make sense.